# Find an object with a data member with a unique value in Java?

Tags: java

I'm doing a Java task that is like a simple bank system with Customer objects and SavingsAccount. I store all Customer objects in an arraylist and I was also planning to do the same with the SavingsAccount objects, but that is perhaps not necessary. Each SavingsAccount has a data member called accountNumber that is unique.

The SavingsAccount also include data members lika accountBalance. So my question is how do I reach a SavingsAccount that has the accountNumber equal to "1002" (For some reason I have them as Strings) and then be able to set or get values from data member, like accountBalance with setAccountBalance? Help is preciated! Thanks!

I create the account object

```
SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount(inAccount);
```

The class SavingsAccount:

```
class SavingsAccount {

// data members
private String accountType;
private String accountNumber;
private double accountInterestRate;
private int accountBalance;

// constructor
public SavingsAccount(String inNumber){
    accountType = "Saving";
    accountNumber = inNumber;
    accountInterestRate = 0.5;
    accountBalance = 0;
}

// get account number
public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

// get account balance
public int getAccountBalance() {
    return accountBalance;
}

// get interest rate
public double getAccountInterestRate(){
    return accountInterestRate;
}

    // set new value to balance
    public void setAccountBalance(int inMoney){
    accountBalance = accountBalance + inMoney;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Since I'm learning Java, I prefer a solution that is not to complicated to use right now. I know how to use arraylist, but I haven't reach to the hashmap yet, and was hoping for a simplier, but perhaps not the best, solution for now? Isn't there a way to reach objects without "collecting" them in arraylist or hashmap?

Comment: you cannot check String with "==" operator. Use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() instead.

Comment: That's right, I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the accounts in an `ArrayList<SavingsAccount>` I suggest you store them in a `HashMap<String, SavingsAccount>`.

Put the account into the map right after creating it:

```
SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount(inAccount);
accountMap.put(inAccount, account);
```

You can then get hold of an account easily and efficiently by doing

```
accountMap.get(accountNumber);
```

---

To make sure that an account mapped to by some account number always indeed has that very account number, I suggest you make `accountNumber` final:

```
...
private final String accountNumber;
...
```

Comment: OK, but must the objects be in a HashMap? Couldn't they be "free" and just select one of them?

Comment: To be able to *find* one you need somewhere to *look* for it. If they're just floating around, you can't really search for it anywhere. You *can* however put the `HashMap` as a static member of the `SavingsAccount` class and add `this` to the map in the `SavingsAccount` constructor, and create a static method like this: `public static getSavingsAccount(String num) { return map.get(num); }`. I suggest you consider using the factory pattern and always ask the `SavingsAccount` for an account object. (This would allow you to avoid ever creating two account objects with the same num.)

Answer (score 0):

I would place them in a Map like

```
final Map<String, SavingsAccount> accounts = new LinkedHashMap<String, SavingsAccount>();

// get an account.
SavingsAccount account = accounts.get(accountKey);

// add an account
accounts.put(accountKey, account);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashing by account number is an effective way of getting a SavingsAccount in constant time. Drop the ArrayList and use a HashMap;

```
HashMap<String, SavingsAccount> map = new HashMap<String, SavingsAccount>();
SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount(inNumber);
map.put(inNumber, account);
```

Then retrieve it with:

```
SavingsAccount account = map.get(inNumber);
```